# Calling correct overload in derived class

Tags: c++, oop, templates, c++03, c++98

Consider the following

```
struct Message
{
  Message() : description("Generic message") {}
  Message(const std::string& d) : description(d) {}

  std::string description;
};

struct MessageType1 : public Message
{
  MessageType1() : Message("MessageType1"), a_boolean(false) {}
  bool a_boolean;
};

// more specific Message types

class AbstractMessagePasser
{
 public:
  virtual ~AbstractMessagePasser();

  void receive(const Message& m) {}
};

class Component1
{
  AbstractMessagePasser* m_fwd;

 public:
  template<class M>
  void send(const M& m)
  {
    m_fwd->receive(m);
  }
};

// more classes like Component1 with a pointer to an AbstractMessagePasser

class MessagePasser : public AbstractMessagePasser
{
  Component1* cp1;
  Component2* cp2;

  using AbstractMessagePasser::receive;      

  // overloads of AbstractMessagePasser::receive() for different message types
  void receive(const MessageType1&)
  {
    // do something
  }

  void receive(const MessageType2&)
  {
    // do something different
  }
};
```

In words, I have a some components, the communication between them is done using different derived types of `Message`. All the communication should be handled in `MessagePasser`. To this end I'd like `MessagePasser` to call the correct overload of `receive()` when a component sends a `Message`, i.e. if a component calls `send(const MessageType1&)` then `receive(const MessageType1)` should be called in `MessagePasser`. However the base class version is always called.

I have also tried template specialization without success (templating `receive` in `AbstractMessagePasser`. Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: Keyword: Dynamic dispatch.

Comment: If all communication should be handled in `MessagePasser`, why does `AbstractMessagePasser` exist?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the receive method virtual. Otherwise it is just a static functin call.

```
class AbstractMessagePasser
{
public:
    virtual ~AbstractMessagePasser();

    virtual void receive(const Message& m) {}
};
```